# While running Spring Boot project getting error like null pointer exception for eureka server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have Spring boot project with the version 3.0.1 and also i am using eureka dependency
and while running getting error as below . Could you please help on this ?

```
'''<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>  
       <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
         <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
 </dependency>'''

  Error:
    '''org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean   'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
at com.hm.bob.odata.BobOdataApplication.main(BobOdataApplication.java:17)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:54)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38)
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
... 14 common frames omitted'''

```
  Could you please help on this?
```